# How to exclude specific IDs from $wpdb->get_results function

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I currently have this code for an ajax search field.

```
$users = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM wp_users WHERE display_name LIKE '%" . esc_attr( $_REQUEST['query'] ) . "%' LIMIT 10" );
```

I only want to limit the results to 10. When the user clicks a load more button, how is this going run and exclude user ids from users that has been previously shown?

Comment: Using where condition with `IN('id1','id2',....)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add **OFFSET** parameter in query. OFFSET is starting record pointer in database, So if you query first time OFFSET will be 0 and for second query it will be 10 and for third query it will be 30 and so on.
You Also need to apply LIMIT to get specific number of records.

Here is official wordpress documentation for this.

[Offset and Limit in Queries](https://codex.wordpress.org/Making_Custom_Queries_using_Offset_and_Pagination)

Hope this is what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

you have to pass an counter variable that increase every time you click on load more,

```
$limit = 10;
$offset = $counter*$limit;
$users = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM wp_users WHERE display_name LIKE '%" . esc_attr( $_REQUEST['query'] ) . "%' LIMIT $offset,$limit" );
```